# How to do 'same' padding in PyTorch if (n - 1) / 2 is no integer value

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, conv-neural-network, padding

I am trying to reconstruct a neural network written in tensorflow. For the convolutional layer, they just use `padding='SAME'`. This doesn't exist in pytorch. I know, that I can calculate the padding with `p = (n - 1) / 2` for stride=1. But what if this doesn't result in an integer value? In my case, n is 4 and I always want to achieve same padding.

Answer (score 0):

Use `math.floor` function to round **down** to the nearest integer or the `math.ceil` function to round **up** to the nearest integer:

```py
import math

# for flooring
p = math.floor((n - 1) / 2))

# for ceiling
p = math.ceil((n - 1) / 2))
```

For example, by default, `pytorch` uses flooring for `MaxPool` layers. So, I think `flooring` is a good starting point.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried to just use integer division with `//`, but this leads to different output dimensions, which is what I have to avoid.

Comment: What about ceiling, does it solve dimension problem?